# How to count inverse with for in php?

Tags: php, count, loops, inverse

***My Problem:* I want to count inverse in the for loop.**

This is the opposite of what I want to do:

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    echo $i;
}
```

If I put `$i--` doesn't works (my server crashes).

Help meeee!

Best Regards,
Adam

Comment: If it crashes your server... something very wrong is going on. Or is it one of those liberal uses of "crash"?

Comment: @Artefacto: What he means is "the PHP script never returns and CPU load goes up". As happens when you write infinite loops.

Comment: It was crashing because I started an infinite loop :P @thetaiko has resolved for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you say `$i--` crashes your server, did you change the initialization and condition for `$i`?

```
for($i=10; $i>=1; $i--){
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: Omg :))) I'm such a noob, yes I changed it, but not this way

And It works thanks :D

Answer (score 10):

If you take the `for` as you wrote and just replace `$i++` with `$i--`, the value of `$i` will be decremented with every iteration (1, 0, -1, -2, etc.) and the looping condition `$i<=10` is always true.

If you want to count backwards, you also need to change the other parts (initialization and looping condition):

```
for ($i=10; $i>=1; $i--){
    echo $i;
}
```

Or you take the last and subtract the current value from it and add the first value to it:

```
for ($first=1, $i=$first, $last=10; $i<=$last; $i++){
    echo $last - $i + $first;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't get it, just doing

```
for($i=10;$i>=1;$i--){
    echo $i;
}
```

is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement

The first expression (expr1) is evaluated (executed) once unconditionally at the beginning of the loop.

In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends.

At the end of each iteration, expr3 is evaluated (executed).